# const arrays in rust - initialise with list comprehension?

Tags: rust, constants

Is there a way to use closures or list comprehension when defining constant arrays in Rust? Suppose we have these three const arrays:

```
const K1 : [i32;8] = [100, 100, 101, 102, 104, 106, 108, 900];
const K2 : [i32;8] = [-100, -100, -101, -102, -104, -106, -108, -900];
const K3 : [i32;8] = [-900, -108, -106, -104, -102, -101, -100, -100];
```

In python K2 and K3 could be expressed as

```
K2=[-x for x in K1]
K3=[-x for x in K1[::-1]
```

Rust has the cute crate which emulates python list comprehension, but I don't think it can be used to define constants. So is there a more elegant solution than simply typing out K2 and K3 as above?

Answer (score 7):

Someday, when Rust has more constant-evaluation abilities, we may be able to write the following:

```rust
const K1: [i32; 8] = [100, 100, 101, 102, 104, 106, 108, 900];
const K2: [i32; 8] = K1.map(|x| -x);
const K3: [i32; 8] = { let mut a = K2; a.reverse(); a };
```

However, for now, neither `array::map()` nor `slice::reverse()` are `const fn`s, so you can't use them in constants. `map` in particular is going to be more trouble because it requires [the ability to define higher-order const fns](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63997) which is not yet available.

However, we can define our own `const` functions to do the specific jobs we need. This requires a lot more code, so it's not a great idea if you have *only one case*, but it could be worthwhile anyway to help readability of the constant definitions, or if these situations come up more than once.

```rust
const K1: [i32; 8] = [100, 100, 101, 102, 104, 106, 108, 900];
const K2: [i32; 8] = array_i32_mul(-1, K1);
const K3: [i32; 8] = array_reverse(K2);

const fn array_i32_mul<const N: usize>(factor: i32, mut a: [i32; N]) -> [i32; N] {
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < N {
        a[i] *= factor;
        i += 1;
    }
    a
}

const fn array_reverse<T: Copy, const N: usize>(mut a: [T; N]) -> [T; N] {
    let mut i = 0;
    while i < N / 2 {
        let from_end = N - i - 1;
        (a[i], a[from_end]) = (a[from_end], a[i]);
        i += 1;
    }
    a
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(K1, K2, K3);
}
```

Notes:

- It's not possible to use `for` loops in `const fn`s yet, because traits aren't supported and `for` uses `Iterator` which is a trait, so we have to use `while` for all our indexing.
- `array_reverse` would not need `T: Copy` if `std::mem::swap()` were const, but it isn't yet.

The advantages of going to this effort over using `Lazy`, as suggested in another answer, are:

- The constants can be used in situations where the numeric values are actually required to be constants — with `Lazy` accessing the value is only possible at run time.
- Accessing the values doesn't require a run-time check for whether they've been initialized yet.
- The type is an array type, rather than something that merely derefs to an array.

Answer (score 1):

I would try with [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/)

I don't find this as elegant as list-comprehensions, but maybe it's enough for the intended usage.

```rust
use once_cell::sync::Lazy;

const K1: [i32; 8] = [100, 100, 101, 102, 104, 106, 108, 900];

const K2: Lazy<[i32; K1.len()]> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let mut k2 = [0; K1.len()];
    k2.iter_mut().zip(K1.iter()).for_each(|(x2, x1)| *x2 = -*x1);
    k2
});

const K3: Lazy<[i32; K1.len()]> = Lazy::new(|| {
    let mut k3 = [0; K1.len()];
    k3.iter_mut().zip(K1.iter().rev()).for_each(|(x3, x1)| *x3 = -*x1);
    k3
});

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", K1);
    println!("{:?}", *K2);
    println!("{:?}", *K3);
}
/*
[100, 100, 101, 102, 104, 106, 108, 900]
[-100, -100, -101, -102, -104, -106, -108, -900]
[-900, -108, -106, -104, -102, -101, -100, -100]
*/
```